# Trying to commit after merge, getting errors on git lint

Tags: eslint, lint

After performing merge, there is this 1 file that I have to push, after git add ., I run this command

```
git commit -m "Merge"
```

This is the output of the command [FAILED] and ✖ are all displaying as red

```
> company@0.0.0 lint-staged
> lint-staged

[STARTED] Preparing lint-staged...
[SUCCESS] Preparing lint-staged...
[STARTED] Running tasks for staged files...
[STARTED] package.json — 313 files
[STARTED] *.{ts,html} — 238 files
[STARTED] *.scss — 17 files
[STARTED] *.json — 24 files
[STARTED] *.{png,jpeg,jpg,gif,svg} — 19 files
[STARTED] cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=5120 eslint --quiet --cache -…
[STARTED] stylelint --allow-empty-input --cache --cache-location=.cache/stylelint/l…
[STARTED] prettier --write
[STARTED] npm run optimize-images:specific --
[FAILED] cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=5120 eslint --quiet --cache --cache-location=.cache/eslint/lint-staged [FAILED]
[FAILED] cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=5120 eslint --quiet --cache --cache-location=.cache/eslint/lint-staged [FAILED]
[SUCCESS] Running tasks for staged files...
[STARTED] Applying modifications from tasks...
[SKIPPED] Skipped because of errors from tasks.
[STARTED] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[FAILED] prettier --write [KILLED]
[FAILED] prettier --write [KILLED]
[FAILED] npm run optimize-images:specific -- [KILLED]
[FAILED] npm run optimize-images:specific -- [KILLED]
[FAILED] stylelint --allow-empty-input --cache --cache-location=.cache/stylelint/lint-staged [KILLED]
[FAILED] stylelint --allow-empty-input --cache --cache-location=.cache/stylelint/lint-staged [KILLED]
[SUCCESS] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[STARTED] Cleaning up temporary files...
[SUCCESS] Cleaning up temporary files...

✖ cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=5120 eslint --quiet --cache --cache-location=.cache/eslint/lint-staged:
The command line is too long.

✖ prettier --write failed without output (KILLED).

✖ npm run optimize-images:specific -- failed without output (KILLED).

✖ stylelint --allow-empty-input --cache --cache-location=.cache/stylelint/lint-staged failed without output (KILLED).
```

Normally this wouldn't error, but I'm thinking why it errored out this time...

Comment: I think the only tag that should be there is `lint` as the question is not git-related: https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged/issues/147

Comment: I'm sorry about the other git tags, I can't remove them, or do you know how I could remove them?

Comment: You should be able to do it by editing the question.